# How to pass JSONObject in HashMap<String, String> Or Map<String, String>

Tags: arrays, json, android-volley

How to pass `JSONObject` in `HashMap<String, String>` Or `Map<String, String>`.

I have also below code used for pass the json value in param but this valid.

```
{
    "user_id" : 6,
    "medicine" : [{
                     "medicine_id" : 3,
                     "event_type" :"after_lunch"
                }]
}
```

### Code :

```
StringRequest stringRequest=new StringRequest(Method.POST, url,volleyListener,volleyErrorListener){
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                HashMap<String, String> param=new HashMap<String, String>();
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObjectStud= new JSONObject();
                    jsonObjectStud.accumulate("stud_id", studId);
                    jsonObjectStud.accumulate("event_type", eventType);
                    JSONArray jsonArrayChild=new JSONArray();
                    jsonArrayChild.put(jsonObjectStud);
                    JSONObject jsonObject= new JSONObject();
                    jsonObject.accumulate("user_id", userId);
                    jsonObject.accumulate("stud", jsonArrayChild.toString());                       
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return param;
            }
}
```

Comment: What about learning Gson or Jackson serializers, i think are good choices, and let you handle it, regards

Comment: yes, personally i use Gson, but Jackson i have heard good things about,  i recommend this: http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-custom-serialization

Comment: Do you understand this problem.

Comment: I have used getParams() method in StringRequest()

Comment: If I am taking it correct, you want to pass JSON Object to some Map as a String value.

Comment: Check updated the question.